# Can we grab iPhone screen before program launch?

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot, screen-capture

Can we grab iPhone screen before program launch? Of course it will be grabbed after application launching. But maybe iOS cashes it somewhere so we can access it.

Comment: Interesting question. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to blur background of the application based on StoryBoard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Access to the system-generated stuff is not safe... You can save the state before the app enter the background,  then  on applicationWillEnterForeground:  method worked you can resume the state.